# How to use Xamarin Droid Binding for Sectioned Recycler View

Tags: xamarin, android-recyclerview, sections

I found a link for Droid Binding of sectioned recycler view, which is [here](https://libraries.io/nuget/SectionedRecyclerview.Droid.Binding)

But, I need to know, how this works, how to I pass header and items list to the adapter.
I need alphabets as headers.